# is it possible to create a non-child process inside a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, fork, multiprocessing

I'm using a [shell process pool API](https://github.com/vtonehundred/shellutils/blob/master/job_pool.sh) at Github,  for a script, as below

```
    function foobar()
    {
       mytask($1);
    }

    job_pool_init 100 0
    tcpdump -i eth0 -w tempcap &            #
    for i in `seq 1 4`;do
      mesg="hello"$i
      job_pool_run foobar $mesg
      sleep 5
    done

    job_pool_wait
    pkill tcpdump                           #
    echo 'all finish'
    job_pool_shutdown
```

if I comment the tcpdump line，
then it works fine, as expected，
but when the tcpdump line is there，
There is a `wait` command in `job_pool_wait`, which waits for the ending of all children process, if there is no such a tcpdump line, it is as expected.
But I want to capture something until all the child processes finish, so I have to use a tcpdump. In this script, tcpdump process is a child process，
`job_pool_wait` will also wait for the ending of tcpdump process, which is not expected.

so a solution is to make tcpdump not a child process，
how can I do it，
or any other solutions?
thanks！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to run `tcpdump` in a sub-shell in the background:

```
(tcpdump -i eth0 -w tempcap &)
```

This should prevent it from appearing as a direct descendant of your script.

Comment: wow, great! it is OK! can you explain a bit about the parenthesis? thanks!

Comment: @misteryes: The parentheses specifies the command within them should be run in a sub-shell. A sub-shell creates a child shell process to run the provided command. The result is that `tcpdump` becomes a grandchild to your script, rather than a child.

Comment: so, atcually it is immediately handed to init process, because there is no real sub-shell, right? I checked using `ps -ef` and get to know its parent pid is 1

Comment: The sub-shell exits immediately, because `tcpdump` is being executed in the background of the sub-shell. When a process loses its parent, the init process takes over as parent.

Comment: I don;t get your point, what do you mean by saying `The sub-shell exits immediately`? you mean the sub-shell appears immediately? What I want to know is when will the sub-shell exit?

Comment: A sub-shell would be a child process that can process more shell commands. The `()` creates the sub-shell, and the command executed is `tcpdump ... &`. Since the command ends with `&`, the sub-shell launches the command in the background. Since the command is running in the background, the sub-shell doesn't wait for it to complete. Since the sub-shell is now done executing the command, it exits. Since the sub-shell exits while the `tcpdump` is still running, the process running `tcpdump` has now lost its parent, so it gets adopted by the init process.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your literal question, yes, run the command with exec. But I doubt that's what you really wanted.

I  think what you really wanted is to be able to wait on specific pid. The wait command takes an optional pid. Either that round need to check when wait returns whether the process that just terminated is a process you're interested in, and wait again if it's not.

Comment: run which command with exec? why?  I'm not waiting on a specific pid,there are so many child processes that need to be waited. I just hope it can wait all child process except the process for `tcpdump`

Comment: @misteryes: wait can receive an array of children's pid. For example, if `pids` is an array of pids: `wait ${pids[@]}` will wait until all of the processes in pids are finished. There are several ways you can create the list of pids. You can append your command with `... & pids+=($!)`. Alternatively, you can use `pids=( $(jobs -p) )` to get an array of all child processes and then remove tcpdump's pids using `pids_minus_tcpdump=( ${pids[@]/$tcpdumppid/} )`.